# Sort by specific value nested array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, tree, nested-object

I'm doing a sorting algorithm exercise and i'm stuck.
I have an array of objects that may contain nested objects like the first, nested on it.

I need to sort all "elements" arrays containing one or more nodes where the "val" property === targetValue are moved to the front of the array.

I need to create a sortObject(object, targetValue) function to do this.

For example:

```
const object = {
  val: 1,
  elements: [
    {
      val: 2,
      children: [
        {
          val: 7,
          elements: [
            {val: 2},
            {val: 18},
            {val: 12}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 4,
      elements: [
        {val: 5},
        {
          val: 6,
          elements: [
            {val: 12},
            {val: 11},
            {val: 10},
            {val: 9},
          ]
        },
        {val: 13}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 3,
      elements: [
        {val: 15}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 17,
      elements: [
        {val: 16},
        {
          val: 2,
          elements: [
            {val: 14},
            {val: 11},
            {
              val: 18,
              elements: [
                {val: 4},
                {val: 11},
                {val: 7}
              ]
            },
            {val: 27},
            {val: 18},
            {val: 29},
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

this would become, if i'm calling sortObject(object, 18), (with the changes noted below)

```
sortedObject = {
  val: 1,
  elements: [
    {
      val: 2,
      elements: [
        {
          val: 7,
          elements: [
            {val: 18}, // <-- this moved up
            {val: 2},
            {val: 12}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 17, // <-- this moved up
      elements: [
        {
          val: 2, // <-- this moved up
          elements: [
            {
              val: 18, // <-- this moved up
              elements: [
                {val: 4},
                {val: 11},
                {val: 7}
              ]
            },
            {val: 18}, // <-- this moved up
            {val: 14},
            {val: 11},
            {val: 27},
            {val: 29},
          ]
        },
        {val: 16}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 4,
      elements: [
        {val: 5},
        {
          val: 6,
          elements: [
            {val: 12},
            {val: 11},
            {val: 10},
            {val: 9},
          ]
        },
        {val: 13}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 3,
      elements: [
        {val: 15}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I started creating a sorting algorithm for it, but i couldn't make pass the first "elements" recursion.. and realized that how i was trying to do it would never work (I was creating a new array, getting the indexes of the child objects with the targetValue, and pushing to a new array..but this wouldn't work with the recursion)
I'm stuck can anyone help?

Comment: why is 17 moved up? please add your try.

Comment: @NinaScholz This is the example given in the description of the exercise..From what i understand, the object with val: 17 moves up because none of the others in the same level has 18, and it contains 18 inside the elements of this one... then the other changes are done inside it. I'm trying to come up with some solution because the other one wasn't working and i deleted it, if i have one, I'll post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and look for the wanted value and store the object if the value is found. Then sort the array by the boolean value if the set contains the object.

```js
const
    sortObject = (object, value) => {
        const
            hasValue = new Set,
            sort = object => {
                let found = object.val === value;
                if (object.elements) {
                    object.elements.forEach(o => found = sort(o) || found);
                    object.elements.sort((a, b) => hasValue.has(b) - hasValue.has(a));
                }
                if (found) hasValue.add(object);
                return found;
            };

        sort(object);
        return object;
    },
    object = { val: 1, elements: [{ val: 2, elements: [{ val: 7, elements: [{ val: 2 }, { val: 18 }, { val: 12 }] }] }, { val: 4, elements: [{ val: 5 }, { val: 6, elements: [{ val: 12 }, { val: 11 }, { val: 10 }, { val: 9 }] }, { val: 13 }] }, { val: 3, elements: [{ val: 15 }] }, { val: 17, elements: [{ val: 16 }, { val: 2, elements: [{ val: 14 }, { val: 11 }, { val: 18, elements: [{ val: 4 }, { val: 11 }, { val: 7 }] }, { val: 27 }, { val: 18 }, { val: 29 }] }] }] };

console.log(sortObject(object, 18));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sort order is defined by how *deep* the occurrence of 18 is, such that the less deep it occurs the earlier it should occur in the array, then I would suggest a kind of bucket sort, where elements that have 18 occurring at the *same* depth, will be placed in the same bucket. The buckets are then concatenated to become the sorted `elements` array:

```js
function sortObject(obj, target) {
    const partition = {};
    let minDepth = 10000; // depth of object should not exceed this limit
    if (obj.elements?.length) {
        for (const child of obj.elements) {
            const depth = sortObject(child, target);
            (partition[depth] ??= []).push(child);
            minDepth = Math.min(minDepth, depth);
        }
        obj.elements = Object.values(partition).flat();
    }
    return obj.val === target ? 0 : minDepth + (minDepth < 10000);
}

const object = {val: 1,elements: [{val: 2,elements: [{val: 7,elements: [{val: 2},{val: 18},{val: 12}]}]},{val: 4,elements: [{val: 5},{val: 6,elements: [{val: 12},{val: 11},{val: 10},{val: 9},]},{val: 13}]},{val: 3,elements: [{val: 15}]},{val: 17,elements: [{val: 16},{val: 2,elements: [{val: 14},{val: 11},{val: 18,elements: [{val: 4},{val: 11},{val: 7}]},{val: 27},{val: 18},{val: 29},]}]}]};
sortObject(object, 18);
console.log(object);
```